# Calculate correct visits in order to decide SKUs for project need

Tags: licensing

We're planning `SC8.2 to 9.2 Azure PaaS migration` and need to decide correct SKUs which would best for our project since the consumption-based license is all about visits.

Any suggestion how should we calculate current & expected visits on the website. Is everybody is using Google analytics or any other method. I think visits is all about session count on our website.
Is Sitecore count visit only on CD server OR request hitting CM, reporting and processing servers?

Answer (score 1):

In my last project, we extracted the monthly visits from google analytics report and based on that we decided the SKU using the SKU table on below link.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/043375

You can go with the above recommendations, BTW in future based on use you will able to change the SKU based on actual traffic and application performance analysis.

Comment: Did you follow this https://www.cloudways.com/blog/checking-concurrent-visitors-with-google-analytics/ for visit counts. 
As per KB article what exactly Visits mean? Is it concurrent visits or sessions count?

Comment: In KB article its a visits per month and you can get this from 1st report in https://www.cloudways.com/blog/checking-concurrent-visitors-with-google-analytics/. It should be session count.

Comment: I couldn't find session count in that link but hope you're referring session count as mentioned in this link https://www.seroundtable.com/google-analytics-sessions-users-18424.html

Comment: Below is how I calculated Approximate visits per month as per KB article:
1. Applied annual date filter in Audience Overview in google analytics
2. Selected Month in top right and choose Sessions from drop-down just below Overview tab if top left
3. Looked at peak in the graph shown and found sessions( visits ) per month

Comment: Yes that's right. I did the same way :)

Comment: Thank you @Anil